# IIS URL Rewrite with a pound/number sign "#"

Tags: iis, url-rewriting, iis-7.5

I have a need to rewrite a url for an invoice that has a "#" in the querystring.  Evidently the "#" is causing IIS to balk somehow.  The rule I have currently is:

^invoice/([_0-9a-z-#]+)

and the action is:

invoice.aspx?id={R:1}

Pretty simple and works fine so long as there's no "#" in the invoice number. Is there any way to include this so it works?

Comment: Unless you properly URL-encode the `#`, you _don’t have_ `#` in the path part of your URL to begin with. You would have a _fragment_, and that does not get send to the server in the first place, because it by definition is supposed to have relevance on the client side only.

Answer (score 1):

Hash Tags in the URL serve a special purpose to the client browser, not to the server.so Browser did not anything after the '#' character.

To resolve this issue you can try this below url rewrite rule:

```
 <rule name="test # in query string" stopProcessing="true">
                <match url="(.*)" />
                <conditions>
                    <add input="{REQUEST_URI}" pattern="invoice/(.+)" />
                </conditions>
                <action type="Redirect" url="invoice.html?id={UrlEncode:{C:1}}" />
            </rule>
```

(.+) accessts all the chracter and {UrlEncode:{}} encode the url in the orignal manner.

[image]

Regards,
Jalpa